# Behaviour of ROUND_HALF_DOWN , Python 3.9.5, decimal module

Tags: python-3.x, linux, decimal, rounding

OS: fedora 34 workstation, GNU/Linux

I am confused. In the decimal module [documentation section "Rounding modes"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes) says,

```
decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN

    Round to nearest with ties going towards zero.
```

I have an example

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

print('----')
getcontext().prec = 4
getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN
print(getcontext())
n1 = Decimal('25.2525') + Decimal('0.003')
print(n1)
```

I was expecting as result 25.25 because the sum results in n1 = 25.2555 has a 5 in the thousandths position, then must go DOWN to 0 and the hundredths position remain the same.

Am I wrong?

why I am getting there 25.26?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which is nearer to 25.2555: 25.26 or 25.25? It certainly isn't a tie. Note that 0.xx55 > 0.xx50

Comment: It looks at all the digits after the precision, not just the next digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says:

> Round to nearest **with ties** going towards zero.

In this particular case there isn't a tie because 25.2555 is closer to 25.26 than it is to 25.25. So it just rounds to the nearest, which is 25.26.

Comment: I was not considering the trailing digits, that allows me to understand the issue.